# Is there an equivalent to '<base>' that works for file paths?

Tags: html, relative-path, radix, server-side-includes

I have a base url that as far as I can tell works for any link that has code like `href="...` but does not work with files that are called by the `include` command.

`<base href="http://.../www/" target="_blank">`

For example, suppose I am one directory down from the directory specified by the base url. The base directory contains, say, `helper.css` and a folder called `includes` that has a file `sidebmenu.htm`. The code on the page that is one directory down

```
`<link href="helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
```

will load `helper.css`. Likewise, any links to other pages inside the base directory and any sub folders are correctly called on.

However,

`<!--#include file="includes/sidemenu.htm"-->`

will not work unless I use `../` to go up one directory

`<!--#include file="../includes/sidemenu.htm"-->`

and then it will work.

Is there something similar to `<base>` that will make the paths to files called on by `include` relative to the same base directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<--!#include` is a server side include. That means that the server already imports the HTML and returns the combined files as one response. The paths there are not urls but actual file paths (that is, if you use the `file` attribute like you do) to html template files on the server. So you could possibly even include files from outside the document root, that is, if your server allows it (apparently [Apache does not](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html)).

The `<base>` tag is to set a base url for subsequent requests by the browser, for instance image urls and css files.

As a side note, maybe you are interested in [HTML5 client side includes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/). This is a different method, no drop in replacement for SSI, and [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) is very poor atm. Interesting reading material, though. ;)